# APACHE 7 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7, classnotfoundexception, catalina

My app runs well on localhost with apache6, but when I uploaded to the server with apache7 it won't run.

```
may 31, 2015 7:31:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
Información: Se ha completado la recarga de este Contexto
may 31, 2015 7:32:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
Información: Falló la recarga del contexto [/SIPEC_Servicios_Web]
may 31, 2015 7:32:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
Advertencia: Error durante el arranque del contexto /SIPEC_Servicios_Web
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SIPEC_Servicios_Web]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1446)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.runm(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: artech/security/api/gamrefreshtoken
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2387)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1796)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: artech.security.api.gamrefreshtoken
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
```

Comment: This is the error you should be trying to resolve , `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: artech.security.api.gamrefreshtoken` and not `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException` .

Comment: Thats exactly the problem i cant find how to fix it!!

Comment: like i said on my localhost with apache 6 runs well

Answer (score 0):

hey look i found the answer.. i just had to removed from the application of web.xml, so you cut a reference to the GAM of the API, it will be able to solve the problem.

```
    <Servlet> 
    <servlet-name> GXOAuthAccessToken </ servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class> Com.Genexus.Webpanels.GXOAuthAccessToken </ servlet-class> 
    </ servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name> GXOAuthAccessToken </ servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern> / oauth / access_token </ url-pattern> 
    </ servlet-mapping>
```